# Making list of factors in a function but return warning error

Tags: r, function, factors

Let say that I have these vectors:

```
time <- c(306,455,1010,210,883,1022,310,361,218,166)
status <- c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)
gender <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1)
```

And I turn it into these data frame:

```
dataset <- data.frame(time, status, gender)
```

I want to list the factors in the third column using this function (p/s: pardon the immaturity. I'm still learning):

```
getFactor<-function(dataset){

result <- list()
result["Factors"] <- unique(dataset[[3]])
return(result)

}
```

And all I get is this:

```
getFactor(dataset)
$Factors
[1] 1

Warning message:
In result["Factors"] <- unique(dataset[[3]]) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I tried using `levels`, but all I get is an empty list. My question is (1) why does this happen? and (2) is there any other way that I can get the list of the factor in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is simple, you just need double brackets around "Factors" :)

In the function

```
result[["Factors"]] <- unique(dataset[[3]])
```

That should be the line.

The double brackets return an element, single brackets return that selection as a list.

Sounds silly, by try this

```
test <- list()

class(test["Factors"])
class(test[["Factors"]])
```

The first class will be of type 'list'. The second will be of type 'NULL'. This is because the single brackets returns a subset as a list, and the double brackets return the element itself. It's useful depending on the scenario. The element in this case is "NULL" because nothing has been assigned to it.

The error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" is because you've asked it to put 3 things into a single element (that element is a list). When you use double brackets you actually put it inside a list, where you can have multiple elements, so it can work!

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you for your help and it works. I love reading your explanation. It's really detail and easy to understand. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback gizmo! I try and keep things as non-technical as I can in descriptions. I figure if you can't explain something simply, it's probably just going to confuse the reader more! Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when you create your data frame, dataset$gender is double vector (which R will automatically do if everything in it is numbers). If you want it to be a factor, you can declare it that way at the beginning:

```
dataset <- data.frame(time, status, gender = as.factor(gender))
```

Or coerce it to be a factor later:

```
dataset$gender <-  as.factor(gender)
```

Then getting a vector of the levels is simple, without writing a function:

```
level_vector <- levels(dataset$gender)
level_vector
```

You're also subsetting lists & data frames incorrectly in your function. To call the third column of dataset, use `dataset[,3]`. The first element of a list is called by `list[[1]]`

Comment: Thank you. I've always confused with the subsetting. The reason I wrote it in a function is because I have a very large data set. This is just a few row of it. And sometimes, the third column is not necessarily with two factors. I try use `dataset[,3]` but it still give me the same error